# Boxplot missing an outlier in R

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have the following data:

```
d = c(58.33333, 58.33333, 56.66667, 45.00000, 60.00000, 70.00000, 61.66667, 51.66667, 58.33333, 71.66667, 50.00000, 63.33333)
```

The summary statistics for the data are:

```
Min.    1st Qu.  Median    Mean    3rd Qu.    Max. 
45.00   55.42    58.33     58.75   62.08      71.67
```

When I do a boxplot of the data using the function `boxplot(d, range=1.5)`, I get the following:

[image]

By my calculations, the lower whisker should only extend down to `55.42 - 1.5*(62.08-55.42) = 45.43`. With that said, the minimum data point (45) should be shown as an outlier but the plot actually extends the whisker down to this minimum. Why does this happen? Is there a rounding procedure I am not aware of that is including 45 into the range? Like something related to how close the two points are (45.43 and 45)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `boxplot` calculates the quartiles using a different method to `summary`, or `quantile`. From `?boxplot.stats`:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e., close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n

Examples:

```
boxplot.stats(d)$stats
[1] 45.00000 54.16667 58.33333 62.50000 71.66667

fivenum(d) # the same
[1] 45.00000 54.16667 58.33333 62.50000 71.66667

quantile(d) # different
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
45.00000 55.41667 58.33333 62.08333 71.66667
```

Specify the method (type) for `quantile` to get the same result:

```
quantile(d, type = 2)
      0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
45.00000 54.16667 58.33333 62.50000 71.66667
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In that regard, how can the boxplot formula be modified so that the plot is calculated using the output of `summary` ?

Comment: You would need to rewrite the `boxplot.stats` function, replacing the line `stats <- stats::fivenum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` with `stats <- stats::quantile(x, type = 2, na.rm = TRUE)`. Alternatively, you could use `geom_boxplot` in `ggplot2` which did display the outlier when I tried it with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a much easier boxplot that includes the outlier using `ggpubr` and check if the value is indeed an outlier with `rstatix`. Here I have loaded the two libraries.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
```

I then ran a simple one-command boxplot with your data, where the value is clearly present:

```
#### Run Simple Box ####
ggboxplot(d) # runs boxplot
```

[image]

Then I checked if it was indeed an outlier, followed by a side-by-side comparison:

```
#### Check Outliers ####
    is_outlier(d) # checks if values are outliers
    d %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      mutate(Outlier = is_outlier(.)) # side-by-side look
```

The second command looks like this and now you can see where the outlier is:

```
          . Outlier
1  58.33333   FALSE
2  58.33333   FALSE
3  56.66667   FALSE
4  45.00000    TRUE
5  60.00000   FALSE
6  70.00000   FALSE
7  61.66667   FALSE
8  51.66667   FALSE
9  58.33333   FALSE
10 71.66667   FALSE
11 50.00000   FALSE
12 63.33333   FALSE
```

Of course you can also spruce things up a bit, and the boxplot is even compatible with `ggplot2` functions without loading them:

```
#### Run Prettier Boxplot ####
d %>% 
  ggboxplot(color = "darkred",
            title = "Boxplot With Single Outlier",
            xlab = "Variable",
            ylab = "Value",
            size = 1.5)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]